# Angular how to check if this page is accessed by a user and to block access for another user?

Tags: angular

I have a page with some data on it.

```
<p-table [value]="mnos" [(contextMenuSelection)]="selectmno" 
[contextMenu]="cm"  >
 <ng-template pTemplate="header"  >
  <tr>
      <th >ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-mno>
      <tr [pContextMenuRow]="rowData"     (click)="test($event,mno)">
          <td>{{mno.id}}</td>
      <td>{{mno.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
<p-contextMenu #cm [model]="items"></p-contextMenu>
```

On click on table it will redirect to another page http://localhost:4200/test . How can I block access to a user if someone already was redirected to this page. Like if I'm already on page http://localhost:4200/test another user that will click on table will be announced that this page is busy.

This is my onClick:

```
test(event, mno){
console.log("On click",event,mno);
this.router.navigate(['/test']);

}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to come up with some backend logic (API) that keeps track of active sessions on the `/test`-page and then write a route guard (for example) that checks if there is currently an active session on the page, if so redirect to the page with the busy-announcement. Because Angular is client-side, visitors cannot directly interact with each other without communicating with an API or something like that.

Comment: I thought that it is possible to set a flag to this page, like if I access it flag is 1, if a close the tab flag is 0, and when the flag is 1 to block access to other users. Also I have API for this test in Java.

Comment: All visitors will get their own application bundle (HTML, Javascript et cetera) when navigating to your website, so they won't know the flag value of each other.
You can work with the flag you just mentioned, but you still have to get the flag value (which somehow represents the session I mentioned) from the API.

Comment: So, i will create a endpoint that will communicate with my front-end, but how to set this flags? I will have something if flag is 1 then return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/test`,data)  else block access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the conversation in the comments you could do the following.
Assuming you have the following files.

**test.component.ts**

```
....
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent {
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
...
export const router: Routes = [
  {path: 'test', component: TestComponent}
];
....
```

You want to somehow check if there's already an active session on the test page.
This is a perfect use case for a route guard, at least I'm convinced.
You can create a route guard that will perform a API call that checks if there's already an active session on the test page. You will need to add some more logic of course, but that'll be the next steps..

**check-active-session.guard.ts**

```
....
@Injectable()
export class CheckActiveSessionGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private api: ApiService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.apiService.activeTestSession().pipe(map(x => {
      // x will be the response from the API
      // Let's pretend it is returning a boolean.
      // It will be true when there's already an active session and false if there's no active session
      // true means user should not pass (because of an active session), false means a user can pass
      if (!x) {
        // No active session, user can pass
        return true;
      } else {
        // Already an active sesssion, user should be redirected
        this.router.navigate(['busy']);
        return false;
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
...
public activeTestSession(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>('api' + '/is_there_already_an_active_session, { observe: 'body', responseType: 'json' });
    }
...
```

Then add the guard to the canActivate property in the routing:

**app.routing.ts** *(New)*

```
...
export const router: Routes = [
  {path: 'test', component: TestComponent, canActivate: [CheckActiveSessionGuard]}
];
....
```

Think this is the minimum implementation of how you can do that.
I can imagine you can create a user session (when the user visits your site, just once) and sending along this session id along with api call, to be able to expand the functionality.